# Extract .zip files using PHP

Tags: php, zip, extract

How can I extract .zip (100%), using PHP?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-extractto.php

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have zziplib installed, you can use this code:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/');
  $zip->close();
  echo 'ok';
} else {
  echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Make sure the user executing php (usually nobody, apache or httpd) have writing privileges on destination dir.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Zip API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php). The algorithm for this is:

1. Open file with [zip_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-open.php)
2. Read directory entry with [zip_read](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-read.php); if false goto step 8
3. Get the name with [zip_entry_name](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-entry-name.php)
4. Open the entry with [zip_entry_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-entry-open.php)
5. Get the data with [zip_entry_read](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-entry-read.php), and store how & where you want
6. Close the entry with [zip_entry_close](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-entry-close.php)
7. Goto step 2
8. Close file with [zip_close](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-close.php)

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: it would be nice, if you gave example code fully.

Comment: I tend to steer clear of writing other people's code for them; the focus of this site is teaching people how to solve a problem, not giving code samples for copy/paste.

Comment: It seems you misunderstood the concept of this site too much. 
pitty, with 5k rep, you should have known that great "teaching" is giving the example/code itself. 
2x2 =4 as easy that your answer needs 20 minutes more time to spend to get the final result.

p.s. you should tell 99% of users of SO to edit their answers (as they give code examples). 
regards and good luck.