# PHP: how extract a zip file?

Tags: php, zip

Is it possible to extract a zip file stored in server using php file operations. The zip file has to be unzipped, I know the location of the file inside server so how can the file will be used for the process. 
Note- Users don't upload any data they just gives the different textual information which is stored as a zip file and it cannot be used to store in database.

Edit1-can we give html's input tag a DEFAULT PATH of file which has to be uploaded so user will not have to select a file they will just need to press upload button

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract .zip files using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653130/extract-zip-files-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;

$res = $zip->open('file.zip');

if ($res === TRUE) 
{
    $zip->extractTo('/extract_path/');
    $zip->close();
}
```